# Replace string values from any Object class - Java

Tags: java, string, replace, field

I am trying to write a generic function which will accept an Object parameter.  It will parse through the Object fields and if it happens to be a String, then it will search for certain characters and replace it.  My proficiency in Java isn't the greatest, so I am stuck at a place where I don't know how to replace the String value in the original Object parameter.  This is the code:

```
    public Object replaceBeanFields(Object obj) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = null;
            value = field.get(obj);
            if (value instanceof java.lang.String) {
                //I want to replace certain characters in this field and return it as part of obj
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

I would appreciate any pointers that would help.  Thanks.

Comment: In part you'd end up with `field.set(obj,newStringValue)` where `newStringValue` is a new String object resulting from your replace operation from value.

Comment: Thank you so much!  you have answered my question.  This worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the value according to your requirements (See  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

And then set the changed value onto the object.

```
        if (value instanceof java.lang.String) {
            String newValue = ((String)value).replace(regex, replacement);
            field.set(obj, newValue);

        }
```

Your case may be different, but in many cases if you're having to use reflection, you may be missing a simpler way to do things.